# How can I exclude a hosting startup assembly in .NET Core 6 when using WebApplication.CreateBuilder()

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to exclude a hosting startup assembly in .NET Core 6 when using `WebApplication.CreateBuilder(...)`.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.WebHost.UseSetting(WebHostDefaults.HostingStartupExcludeAssembliesKey, "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Watch.BrowserRefresh");
```

The above code snippet results in an exception:

> The hosting startup assemblies exclude list changed from "" to "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Watch.BrowserRefresh". Changing the host configuration using WebApplicationBuilder.WebHost is not supported. Use WebApplication.CreateBuilder(WebApplicationOptions) instead.

I checked the suggested `WebApplicationOptions` object but the only properties it has are:

```
public string[]? Args { get; init; }
public string? EnvironmentName { get; init; }
public string? ApplicationName { get; init; }
public string? ContentRootPath { get; init; }
public string? WebRootPath { get; init; }
```

Nothing above mentions hosting startup assemblies. I suspect that the warning/error message is used for any reconfiguration of host object, regardless of whether that particular property can be handled by this options object...

I was thinking if there is some args that allow exclusion of hosting startup assemblies then I could just inject args into the array, but I don't know of any such arguments.

I also found mention of an assembly attribute for `HostingStartup`, but I couldn't find an equivalent attribute for Excluding a hosting startup assembly.

Am I missing something? Is there a better way? I'm thinking the only way may be to fallback to `Host.Create*Builder` methods and then build it all up myself but it feels like I'll be potentially opening a whole new can of worms for my already built out application.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Valid question. We often have issues in dev that we suspect is related to BrowserRefresh functionality, which is something we don't use at all, so we want to disable it entirely for this project. I've seem some posts on how to disable it in VS but within VS code I can't find anything. More generally I'd like to know if WebAppplication.CreateBuilder has any mechanism to support the exclusion of hosting startup assemblies.

Comment: Perhaps you just need to use `WebApplication.CreateSlimBuilder(...)` or `WebApplication.CreateEmptyBuilder(...)` instead then?

Comment: @DavidG I tried to do that, but it looks like those functions were added in .Net 8 and we're still on .Net 6 for this particular project. I'm open to other suggestions, but I'll keep that in mind if we manage to make the jump to .Net 8.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using Environment Variables for excluding hosting startup assemblies.

```
set ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPEXCLUDEASSEMBLIES=Microsoft.AspNetCore.Watch.BrowserRefresh
```

Comment: Yeah, we'll probably need this, and this is good enough for testing my proposed solution, but we'll want something that isn't so susceptible to how exactly the server is configured if possible (I find env variables always manage to fall through the sieves, and this is one that doesn't have as obvious an effect if someone forgets to set it).

Comment: @BarakGall For this concern you could try setting the environment variable from within your application code before the host builder is invoked.e.g `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPEXCLUDES", "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Watch.BrowserRefresh");
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
// Continue with the rest of your setup...` To avoid this behavior altogether and to have more control, as you mentioned, you might need to revert to using the `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder` and configure the web host explicitly in .NET 6.

Comment: Thank you Jalpa. I didn't realize I could modify the env variables within a running C# context (for some reason I thought this was limited to change the env variables in sub-processes). Will definitely give this a shot!